# Angularjs - Dynamic configuration based on Environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a sample angular APP - app.js

```
angular
    .module('myUiApp', [
        'restangular',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngCookies',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.sortable',
        'smart-table',
        'config'
    ])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $sceProvider, $logProvider, RestangularProvider, config) {
        RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(config.apiBaseUrl);
        RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
//routing here
.....
});
```

my Config.js looks like -

```
angular.module('config', []).service('config', function($location, ENV) {
    return ENV.dev;
});
```

my constants.js looks like -

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('config', []).constant('ENV', (function() {
    return {
    dev: {
    appBaseUrl:'http://localhost:9000/',
    apiBaseUrl:'http://localhost:8082/api/'
    }
}
})());
```

I am getting the error saying, Failed to instantiate module myUiApp due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: config.

My assumption is injecting config module will invoke the service, which in turn return the json object. any thoughts or suggesstions to do this dynamic config better?

Answer (score 0):

You can only inject `providers` into an angular `.config()` block. You're attempting to inject a `service`, and that is likely the cause of your error.

Also, you have `angular.module('config', [])` in two different places. This should only be used once to instantiate the module. Use `angular.module('config')` (without the second argument) subsequently to reference that module.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid calling the module `config`, in favor of something that isn't a method used by angular `module.config()` -- maybe `myConfigModule`

Secondly, make sure your script includes the `constants.js` file and the `Config.js` file before it includes the app.js file

Lastly double check that this situtation is not affecting you:

defining the module twice with `angular.module('config', [])` ( emphasis on the **[ ]** ..) When you define the module with the square brackets, you are saying "New Module". In the second file that you include, change it to `angular.module('config')` -- or, combine the files into this:

```
angular.module('myConfigModule', [])
.constant('ENV', (function() {
return {
    dev: {
        appBaseUrl:'http://localhost:9000/',
        apiBaseUrl:'http://localhost:8082/api/'
        }
    }
}).service('config', function($location, ENV) {
    return ENV.dev;
});
```

UPDATE: And typically I see this syntax for controllers, services, anything that is injecting anything else

```
.service('config', ['$location', 'ENV', function($location, ENV) {
     return ENV.dev;
}]); // see beginning and end of square bracket
//  also add new injected modules to both the array (surrounded by quotes) and the function
```

Comment: Thanks!. In my app.js I DI'd the myConfigModule and config service. Still am getting "Unknown provider: config".

Comment: i got it working. Thanks for both of your comments. One quick question.. How to inject a service in the app.js config() block?

Comment: inject the service with the syntax in the updated answer